# Issue with request in RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, ios4, restkit

I'm new to restkit and iphone development and I have a question related to sending a request in restkit.

I have a server side application running on my server with real IP (lets say A.B.C.D) and my application listening port 8001.
Now I want to send a request from my ios application by resktik to A.B.C.D:8001, my mobile app code looks like this:

In my appdelegate I have:

[RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"A.B.C.D"];

In my viewcontroller I have:

const bool isNetAvailable = [[RKClient sharedClient] isNetworkReachable];

```
if (!isNetAvailable)

{
    NSLog(@"Network is not available");
    return;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Network is available");
}

[[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/contacts" delegate:self];
```

So when I'm initializing RKClient with only A.B.C.D looks like everything with reachability is ok, but sending request failed because I can't send request to the 8001 port, get:@"/contacts" looks the right way but request will not be sent to the 8001, adding 8001 to the IP address during the RKCLient initialization failing.

Could you please help me to understand how should I send a request to IP:Port in RestKit?
Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Guys I've found the problem.

I need to use:

[RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://A.B.C.D:port"];

instead of:

[RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"A.B.C.D"];

http:// is required all the time :)